# How to extend tensorflow's GPU memory from system RAM

Tags: deep-learning, gpu, tensorflow

I want to train googles object detection with faster_rcnn_with resnet101 using mscoco dataset[code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection). I used only 10,000 images for training purpose.I used graphics: GeForce 930M/PCIe/SSE2. NVIDIA Driver Version:384.90. here is the picture of my GeForce.[image]

And I have 8Gb RAM but in tensorflow gpu it is showed 1.96 Gb.

[image: system configuration][image: terminal show of GPU]. Now How can I extend my PGU's RAM. I want to use full system memory.

Answer (score 2):

You can train on the cpu to take advantage of the RAM on your machine. However, to run something on the gpu it has to be loaded to the gpu first. Now you can swap memory in and out, because not all the results are needed at any step. However, you pay with a very long training time and I would rather advise you to reduce the batch size. Nevertheless, details about this process and implementation can be found here: https://medium.com/@Synced/how-to-train-a-very-large-and-deep-model-on-one-gpu-7b7edfe2d072.

Comment: I have already ran on CPU. But I want to run on GPU.Why tensorflow gpu is only 1.96 GB? I'm sure you have seen my system RAM(8GB) @Thomas Pinetz

Comment: The gpu uses its own memory and you possess a GPU with only 2 GB of memory. If you want to calculate stuff on the gpu you have to load the data onto the gpu and therefore into the gpu memory. You should probably take a look at cuda kernels and how to load data onto a gpu to understand that better.